# Android Custom ArrayAdapter getting null after onpostexecute

Tags: android

I'm trying to get data from API then show the image on a gridview.

I'm able to get data from the api and put the value (url image) to custom adapter that i created on onpostexecute method.

But it didn't show anything on the grid.the value is null

I've been searching for this solution for two days

Can someone help me fix this?

Here is my code :

MainActivityFragment.java

```
    public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private MovieAdapter movieAdapter;
    MovieList[] movieList;

    public MainActivityFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<MovieList>());

        GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void fetchMoviesData(){
        try {

            SharedPreferences perf = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            String sortCateg = perf.getString(getString(R.string.pref_sort_key), getString(R.string.sort_value_popular));

            fetchMovieDataTask fwd = new fetchMovieDataTask();
            fwd.execute(sortCateg).get();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Failed retreive movies data!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        fetchMoviesData();

    }

    public class fetchMovieDataTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,MovieList[]>{

        private final String LOG_TAG = fetchMovieDataTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected MovieList[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

            String movieStr = null;
            String sortOrder = params[0];

            try{


                final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+sortOrder;
                final String API_KEY = "api_key";

                Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(API_KEY,BuildConfig.theMovieDbApiKey)
                        .build();

                URL url = new URL(buildUri.toString());

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

                if(inputStream == null){
                    movieStr = null;
                }
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    stringBuffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if(stringBuffer.length() == 0){
                    return null;
                }

                movieStr = stringBuffer.toString();
            }catch(IOException e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Error",e);
                movieStr = null;
            }finally {
                if(urlConnection != null){
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }

                if(bufferedReader != null){
                    try{
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    }catch(final  IOException e){
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Error Closing Reader",e);
                    }
                }
            }

            try{
                return getMoviePosterFromJson(movieStr);
            }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(MovieList[] result) {
            if(result != null){
                movieAdapter.clear();
                movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), Arrays.asList(result)); 
            }
        }

        private Date stringToDate(String aDate,String aFormat) {

            if(aDate==null) return null;
            ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
            SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat(aFormat);
            Date stringDate = simpledateformat.parse(aDate, pos);
            return stringDate;

        }

        private MovieList[] getMoviePosterFromJson(String movieJsonStr)
                throws JSONException {

            final String BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";
            final String TMDb_RESULT = "results";
            final String TMDb_POSTER  = "poster_path";
            final String TMDb_TITLE  = "original_title";
            final String TMDb_DATE  = "release_date";
            final String TMDb_VOTE  = "vote_average";
            final String TMDb_OVERVIEW  = "overview";


            JSONObject movieJson = new JSONObject(movieJsonStr);
            JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray(TMDb_RESULT);

            movieList = new MovieList[movieArray.length()];


            for(int i = 0; i < movieArray.length() - 1; i++) {
                String title;
                String poster;
                Integer year;
                String rating;
                String overview;


                JSONObject movieObject = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
                poster = BASE_URL + movieObject.getString(TMDb_POSTER);
                title = movieObject.getString(TMDb_TITLE);
                year = stringToDate(movieObject.getString(TMDb_DATE),"yyy-MM-dd").getYear();
                rating = movieObject.getString(TMDb_VOTE);
                overview = movieObject.getString(TMDb_OVERVIEW);

                movieList[i] = new MovieList(title,poster,year,rating,overview);
            }

            return movieList;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

public MovieAdapter movieAdapter;
MovieList[] movieList;

public MainActivityFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<MovieList>());

    GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
    fetchMoviesData();

    return rootView;
}

public void fetchMoviesData(){
    try {

        SharedPreferences perf = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String sortCateg = perf.getString(getString(R.string.pref_sort_key), getString(R.string.sort_value_popular));

        fetchMovieDataTask fwd = new fetchMovieDataTask();
        fwd.execute(sortCateg).get();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Failed retreive movies data!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

public class fetchMovieDataTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,MovieList[]>{

    private final String LOG_TAG = fetchMovieDataTask.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected MovieList[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        String movieStr = null;
        String sortOrder = params[0];

        try{
            //http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=e4a8053d4e3bab726a20dcb2c12897f3

            final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+sortOrder;
            final String API_KEY = "api_key";

            Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(API_KEY,BuildConfig.theMovieDbApiKey)
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(buildUri.toString());

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            if(inputStream == null){
                movieStr = null;
            }
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                stringBuffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if(stringBuffer.length() == 0){
                return null;
            }

            movieStr = stringBuffer.toString();
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Error",e);
            movieStr = null;
        }finally {
            if(urlConnection != null){
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

            if(bufferedReader != null){
                try{
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }catch(final  IOException e){
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Error Closing Reader",e);
                }
            }
        }

        try{
            return getMoviePosterFromJson(movieStr);
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MovieList[] result) {
        if(result != null){
            GridView gridView = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

            movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), Arrays.asList(result));
            gridView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
        }
    }

    private Date stringToDate(String aDate,String aFormat) {

        if(aDate==null) return null;
        ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
        SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat(aFormat);
        Date stringDate = simpledateformat.parse(aDate, pos);
        return stringDate;

    }

    private MovieList[] getMoviePosterFromJson(String movieJsonStr)
            throws JSONException {

        final String BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";
        final String TMDb_RESULT = "results";
        final String TMDb_POSTER  = "poster_path";
        final String TMDb_TITLE  = "original_title";
        final String TMDb_DATE  = "release_date";
        final String TMDb_VOTE  = "vote_average";
        final String TMDb_OVERVIEW  = "overview";


        JSONObject movieJson = new JSONObject(movieJsonStr);
        JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray(TMDb_RESULT);

        movieList = new MovieList[movieArray.length()];


        for(int i = 0; i < movieArray.length() - 1; i++) {
            String title;
            String poster;
            Integer year;
            String rating;
            String overview;


            JSONObject movieObject = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
            poster = BASE_URL + movieObject.getString(TMDb_POSTER);
            title = movieObject.getString(TMDb_TITLE);
            year = stringToDate(movieObject.getString(TMDb_DATE),"yyy-MM-dd").getYear();
            rating = movieObject.getString(TMDb_VOTE);
            overview = movieObject.getString(TMDb_OVERVIEW);

            movieList[i] = new MovieList(title,poster,year,rating,overview);
        }

        return movieList;
    }
}
```

}
**ERROR EDIT 2**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                  at com.example.william.themovieapps.MainActivityFragment$fetchMovieDataTask.onPostExecute(MainActivityFragment.java:174)
                                                                                  at com.example.william.themovieapps.MainActivityFragment$fetchMovieDataTask.onPostExecute(MainActivityFragment.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try one thing try to print the value of poster url just before you are loading image in adapter and check as you are getting or not  the value?

Answer (score 0):

**onPostExecute** should looks like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MovieList[] result) {
        if(result != null){
            movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), Arrays.asList(result)); 
            gridView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
        }
    }
```

**Edit 1:**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MovieList movieList = getItem(position);

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.poster_griditem_layout,parent,false);

    Picasso
            .with(getContext())
            .load(movieList.poster)
            .fit()
            .into((ImageView) convertView);

    return convertView;
}
```

**Edit 2:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<MovieList>());

    GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
    fetchMoviesData();

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I ve tried your code still no luck  GridView gridView = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

                movieAdapter.clear();
                movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), Arrays.asList(result)); 
                gridView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);

Comment: I hve an error :  java.lang.NullPointerException at onPostExecute

Comment: @william, can you please post your crash logcat and MovieAdapter code

Comment: @william, edited with Edit 1 tag, and I can not see the logcat crash line because inside scroll, can you please paste line here

Comment: changed the code but still hv the same error. If i delete "gridView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);" , my app didnt crash even though the error still there

Comment: @william, please post logcat crash in your answer

Comment: i posted down below

Comment: @william, I have edited my code with tag Edit 2, use it, it will help you.

Comment: ive change it (edit2) but still got an error.I posted my changes and logcat above.please check it out thanks for ur help

Comment: @william, use execute() instead of get() in Async task

Answer (score 0):

@Hiren Patel , here is my code and logcat : 
[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIdUQ.png)

MovieAdapter.java

```
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MovieList> {

public MovieAdapter(Context context, List<MovieList> movieList){
    super(context,0,movieList);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MovieList movieList = getItem(position);

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.poster_griditem_layout,parent,false);
    }
    Picasso
            .with(getContext())
            .load(movieList.poster)
            .fit()
            .into((ImageView) convertView);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: you have already set adapter in _onCreateView() and again set in _onPostExecute()_ method. You just need to notify your adapter in _onPostExecute()_

Comment: like this ? movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), Arrays.asList(result));
                movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();.the app is running, but still the image didnt show up

Comment: This should be removed _movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), Arrays.asList(result));_

Comment: ive change it but still no image.if i remove "movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), Arrays.asList(result)); " when will the movieadapter get the value?

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys its my mistake.i hv null data in my array.solve it now.thanks for all the help